# Is it right for the husband to divorce his wife because of financial constraints?

Tags: sharia, talaq

Is it right for the husband to ask for divorce just because he is facing financial trouble due to losing a job because of a license (he was a doctor) and he is finding it difficult to get a job. I am stable and I offered help for him but he is refusing. He told me that he doesn't want to do it but is forced to by Islam? Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Due to Islamic rules, there is no need to divorce a wife because of losing jobs! Because the divorce is the worst Halal in Islam. And according to a Hadith from Mohammad (pbuh), the sky is shaking when a divorce happening.

But in your case, your husband may be frightened to be or feel ashamed in front of you. So there is two general steps to solve your problem. First of all, let him to have thinking about this and let him know that you will be steady near him in poverty and the second step is not to suggest him solution such as, I myself will work or I will help you and etc.

If your desired result doesn't happened it is better to call a psychologist as a consultant.